Can I install tensorrt 8.6.1 on jetson nano?
I encountered a difficult problem when deploying an RT-DETR variant model on my Jetson Nano, Below is some of my log:
[03/30/2024-17:21:45] [W] [TRT] onnx2trt_utils.cpp:366: Your ONNX model has been generated with INT64 weights, while TensorRT does not natively support INT64. Attempting to cast down to INT32.
[03/30/2024-17:21:45] [W] [TRT] onnx2trt_utils.cpp:392: One or more weights outside the range of INT32 was clamped
[03/30/2024-17:21:46] [I] [TRT] /model.2/ma/MatMul: broadcasting input1 to make tensors conform, dims(input0)=[400,1,256][NONE] dims(input1)=[1,256,256][NONE].
[03/30/2024-17:21:46] [I] [TRT] /model.2/ma/MatMul_1: broadcasting input1 to make tensors conform, dims(input0)=[400,1,256][NONE] dims(input1)=[1,256,256][NONE].
[03/30/2024-17:21:46] [I] [TRT] /model.2/ma/MatMul_2: broadcasting input1 to make tensors conform, dims(input0)=[400,1,256][NONE] dims(input1)=[1,256,256][NONE].
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [I] [TRT] /model.19/decoder/layers.0/self_attn/MatMul: broadcasting input1 to make tensors conform, dims(input0)=[300,1,256][NONE] dims(input1)=[1,256,256][NONE].
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [I] [TRT] /model.19/decoder/layers.0/self_attn/MatMul_1: broadcasting input1 to make tensors conform, dims(input0)=[300,1,256][NONE] dims(input1)=[1,256,256][NONE].
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [I] [TRT] /model.19/decoder/layers.0/self_attn/MatMul_2: broadcasting input1 to make tensors conform, dims(input0)=[300,1,256][NONE] dims(input1)=[1,256,256][NONE].
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [I] [TRT] No importer registered for op: GridSample. Attempting to import as plugin.
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [I] [TRT] Searching for plugin: GridSample, plugin_version: 1, plugin_namespace: 
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:773: While parsing node number 863 [GridSample -> "/model.19/decoder/layers.0/cross_attn/GridSample_output_0"]:
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:774: --- Begin node ---
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:775: input: "/model.19/decoder/layers.0/cross_attn/Reshape_5_output_0"
input: "/model.19/decoder/layers.0/cross_attn/Reshape_6_output_0"
output: "/model.19/decoder/layers.0/cross_attn/GridSample_output_0"
name: "/model.19/decoder/layers.0/cross_attn/GridSample"
op_type: "GridSample"
attribute {
  name: "align_corners"
  i: 0
  type: INT
}
attribute {
  name: "mode"
  s: "bilinear"
  type: STRING
}
attribute {
  name: "padding_mode"
  s: "zeros"
  type: STRING
}

[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:776: --- End node ---
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] [TRT] ModelImporter.cpp:779: ERROR: builtin_op_importers.cpp:4870 In function importFallbackPluginImporter:
[8] Assertion failed: creator && "Plugin not found, are the plugin name, version, and namespace correct?"
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] Failed to parse onnx file
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [I] Finish parsing network model
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] Parsing model failed
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] Failed to create engine from model.
[03/30/2024-17:21:47] [E] Engine set up failed
&&&& FAILED TensorRT.trtexec [TensorRT v8201] # /usr/src/tensorrt/bin/trtexec --onnx=best.onnx --saveEngine=best.engine

I tried upgrading the version of Tensorrt, but couldn't find any tutorials. So I want to ask, does anyone know if Tensorrt8.6 can be installed on Jetson Nano, or does anyone have any other solutions? If someone could tell me the solution, I would be extremely grateful.
My tensorrt version is 8.2.1 now
